# How to make MySQL Workbench forget I renamed a table?

Tags: mysql, synchronization, database-schema, mysql-workbench

Early on in my design phase I made the mistake of renaming a table and then creating a new table with the old name. For some reason, MySQL Workbench decided to remember this fact *very well*. Now every time I try to synchronize with a database, MySQL Workbench wants to rename the (new) table back to its old name.

I did this:

1. Rename my_table => my_new_table
2. Create new table called 'my_table'

And now MySQL Workbench insists this would be the right way to proceed:

1. Rename my_new_table => my_table
2. Drop my_new_table

That's clearly a bug in its own right, but how is MySQL Workbench keeping track of what it has done with the tables of a random DB? Is there some metadata somewhere I can clear to make MySQL Workbench to believe that this change has already taken place and need not to be repeated? Clearly Workbench is doing more than just a diff between the model and the existing database...

(I realize I could just ignore the the particular step in synchronization process, but I don't want to do it every time I synchronize and of course any changes to these two particular tables would be never carried out...)

Answer (score 2):

Managed to work around the issue by running synchronization once with "skip DB changes and update model only". Unclear whether there are bits of the schemata out of sync or not, but at least new changes now carry over.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming an object and creating a new one with the same name is a special case which makes it quite difficult for the synchronization process. The reason is that Workbench uses the names to find objects (as there is no other identification mechanism like UUIDs or similar). So extra steps are done to find such a rename situation. Workbench explicitly keeps the old name to have a way to find what to sync how.